# Rails join array inside map without escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of hashes that I map into a string
Example:

```
array_of_hashes = [{
  :me => 'happy',
  :you => 'notsohappy',
  :email => [
    {"Contact"=>"", "isVerified"=>"1"},
    {"Contact"=>"me@example.com", "isVerified"=>"1"},
    {"Contact"=>"you@example.com", "isVerified"=>"1"}
  ] 
},{another instance here...}]
```

Now I want to convert this to a new array that will give me:

```
["happy", "notsodhappy", "me@example.com", "you@example.com"]
```

I need to map and reject empty email addresses in the "email" array of hashes.

So far I tried:

```
array_of_hashes.map{|record| [
  record['me'],
  record['you'],
  record['email'].map { |email| email['Contact']}.reject { |c| c.empty? }.join('", "')
] }
```

But this returns `["happy", "notsohappy", "me@example.com\", \"you@example.com"]`

The quotes are escapes even if I add `.html_safe` after the `.join`

In short, it's insisting to keep the joined array a single string. I need it split to separate strings... as many as are in the array.

I need to get rid of these quotes because I am trying to export the array as CSV and so far it's not splitting the email addresses to separate columns.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_of_hashes.map do |h|
  [h[:me], h[:you]].push(
    h[:email].map {|e|e["Contact"]}.reject(&:empty?) 
  ).flatten
end

# => [["happy", "notsohappy", "me@example.com", "you@example.com"], ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = []
array_of_hashes.each do |hash|
  single_result = []
  single_result << hash[:me]
  single_result << hash[:you]
  hash[:email].each do |email|
   single_result << email["Contact"] if email["Contact"].present?
  end
  results << single_result
  return results
end
```

This will results : -

```
2.3.1 :091 > results
 => [["happy", "notsohappy", "me@example.com", "you@example.com"], ["happy", "notsohappy", "me@example.com", "you@example.com"], ["happy", "notsohappy", "me@example.com", "you@example.com"]]
```

Comment: Although this could work, I needed to avoid avoid using .each in this instance because it's slower and less efficient/concise. @max was spot on this time, but I appreciate you taking the time to answer!

Comment: @max Is map faster than each, so far as i heard that map internally go through each loop?

Comment: The difference in speed is most likely negligible, its more a question of writing idiomatically correct Ruby. If anything `.map` should be slightly faster since Ruby can make optimizations.  `.each` should only be used when you are only concerned with the side effects. When transforming arrays / hashes / collections you always want to use `.map` or `.each_with_object` as it makes it very clear that the return value is important - not the side effects.